# JavaFX ListView doesn't support String.format?

Tags: java, string, listview, javafx, format

While using JavaFX, I've found that when I want to display a formatted string, the format doesn't work in the list itself. If I try to print it in the console, it works fine. code:

```
package listviewtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLDocumentController extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Listview string format test");
    ListView<String> view = new ListView();
    populateView(view);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view, 800, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void populateView(ListView view) {
    String output;
    ObservableList<String> outputList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //first outputstring
    output = String.format("%-50s%-50s%-50s", "shortText", "shortText", "shortText");
    System.out.println(output);
    outputList.add(output);

    //second outputstring
    output = String.format("%-50s%-50s%-50s", "thisIsALongerTextThanBefore", "thisIsALongerTextThanBefore", "thisIsALongerTextThanBefore");
    System.out.println(output);
    outputList.add(output);

    view.setItems(outputList);
}
}
```

Someone knows what's up?

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work"? I see the same result in Console and in the JavaFX Frame. Or I don't know what to look for

Comment: Ditto. The only thing I can think of is that the lines don't align in the JavaFX app, but that's because you're not using a monospaced font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a monospace font in the ListView. Just add this to your css file:

```
.list-cell 
{
    -fx-font-family: "monospace";
}
```

Or better: use a TableView, since you have multiple columns.

Comment: Used the monospace font, because the Tableview is hard to work with if it are just Strings that i need to display (without java properties)